# Link to Order Detail from Order Confirmation Email

Tags: magento2, order-email

I'd like the customer to be able to click a link from their order confirmation email that leads them to the order detail page on the website.

Is this possible out-of-the-box? If not, how would you recommend building this out?

Edit: could a valid solution involve just linking to /sales/order/view/order_id/[order id here]?